# Maxima greek symbols display but dont work?

Tags: maxima

I am trying to calculate the energy of a photon in (wx)Maxima, using physical_constants and ezunits:

`` |lambda| : 800 * 10^-9 ` m; ``

Where | denotes Escape... which displays correctly as a greek lambda, but wxMaxima does not confirm the value as it does usually.

So next I try to use E = h*c/lambda

``` constvalue (%h * %c / |lambda|) `` J; ```

But again wxMaxima does not show any result.

Everything works fine if I use `lambda` spelled in full instead of a greek symbol...

Is the `|greek|` only good for text inputs?

Comment: Works for me, answer is 2.483056875494879*10^-19, maxima 5.40 / wxmaxima 15.08.2 / Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Well, `lambda` is the name of a built-in function in Maxima (namely the function that creates unnamed functions or lambda expressions as they are called) so maybe Maxima is getting confused about that. Can you use `%lambda` or some other variation? By the way, are you getting the results you need from ezunits? I wrote the ezunits package so naturally I'm curious to know if people find it useful.

Comment: @Michael: ah, my version of wxMaxima is 13.04.2

Comment: @Robert: The results are correct as far as I can tell, it's just that I wanted the formulae not to have spelled out greek letters (entering them fully spelled I don't mind, it just reads nicer when I come back to the project later).. Considering Michael's remark apparently its just me using an old version...

Comment: @propaganda It may be possible to use a different name (e.g. `%lambda`) and to assign an appropriate display symbol to that name so that you type in the name, and it is displayed as a Greek letter lambda. I don't know enough about wxMaxima to say exactly how one would go about it.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple: lambda denotes the anonymous lambda function and that one can not be used as a symbol. Use %lambda instead.

A similar thing applies to phi: phi can be used as a symbol, but %phi is a constant with the value 1.61... (golden ratio).

Taking a derivative with respect to %phi instead of phi will for that reason always result in 0 ;-)